# kibana retrieve term values between a given time interval

Tags: logstash, kibana, kibana-4

I am pretty new to Kibana.

I am logging ssh access hits and I want to compare the access hit counts during night time vs day time. How can I get this data? Also, How can I visualize this?

Also, what if I want to compare hits on weekends vs weekdays?

I can only see continuous time-line on X-axis in the visualization tab.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Your question is very useful & important for time based analysis in Kibana.The answer is based on Kibana 4.1.

For example you want to create visualizations for day vs week:-

1. Click on Visualize tab.

2. Select Line Chart & select from a new search.

3. Select Count in Y-Axis Metric

4. Select Date Range  in **X-Axis agregation**, select date field in **Field** option, in From field option input the range such as :- now-1W & corresponding mention in To field option as :now-1d

5. Then click Split Lines & select terms and its field to display top N results for that time range.

Hope it answers your query.

Comment: Kindly marks this answer as Accept if it solves your query :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use hits chart, or trends. Try use trends with 12 hours difference - and that would be day and night for example. Also you can tag your log entries with spec tags depending on time you sent them to server.